# How to type all the math, stat, greek, equations EFFICIENTLY in libreoffice?

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, keyboard-layout

I am preparing a report related to physics which is full of Greek, stat and calculus things, I know there is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110909/type-greek-and-other-physics-symbols-in-libreoffice-impress) question how to insert a Greek symbol, but my problem is I cant fiddle with a drop down/ scroll list for for every symbol(my paper in FULL of those), is there a way to do something with my keyboard layout, and turn it into something like the one  Tony Stark uses in Ironman(I am not kidding please). I am literally tired for this fiddle-work for half of the day and have completed just 2 sheets, hmmm.

Comment: That is why LaTeX exist: greek, stat and calculus things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTex is *the* standard document markup language for scientific papers. It's pretty hard to get in to for beginners, but very much worth the effort. Given your time constraints I would advise you to do the following:

Use a combination of [TexMaths](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/) (for LaTex integration into LibreOffice) and a LaTex GUI equation editor like [Daum Equation Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/daum-equation-editor/dinfmiceliiomokeofbocegmacmagjhe) (requires Google Chrome / Chromium but works fine offline) to create your formulae.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of being able to do that in libre office.

I would suggest you try using Latex though. There is a very comprehensive Introduction/Manual available at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX. Once you get the hang of it, writing scientific papers, especially with a lot of symbols and math, is much faster than doing it in a 'conventional' text editor. It is not exactly what Tony Stark uses i guess, but much faster than scrolling through drop down menus for every little symbol.

Comment: i have 1.2d days left to complete the report, should i seriously learn latex and then complete it?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by other people answering, [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) is definitely the best option by far for future reports you're going to need but seeing your time frame I wouldn't recommend it.

1. Otherwise an option in your case could be to re-keybind some keys you're not using while typing in Libre Office, I'd suggest to keybind the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys to the different required shortcuts for the letters while you type up your work, and revert them back afterwards (I'm not a Libre Office user myself but I'd assume it should be possible). As a reminder to re-keybind or recreate your own shortcuts you go to:

   - Sytem settings
   - Keyboard
   - Shortcuts
   - Custom Shortcuts
2. As a last resort there is the good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> by keeping two documents side by side as below with your most used letters, that way at least you won't have to open up the insert list each time and search through it, though I already acknowledge this is only a slight workaround until I can find out in detail how to make the previous option I suggested work.

   [image]

Hope this helps and good luck with your report!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the autocorrect option! It converts every (C) in all my figure caption to the copyright symbol. It can replace anything with anything you tell it to do so. You can make some rules such as replace %alpha with alpha symbol just like this:

[image: rules in autocorrect to write symbols]

and voila!

Answer (score -3):

Latex is old & gone except or those who are in their 40s...Use Daum equation Editor (Chrome plugin), a small plugin for a trivial equation editing

Comment: This is simply not true, have a look here to see why latex is still valid: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-should-i-use-latex